# Autodesk Forge, How can I display the tiles inside the scene

Tags: autodesk, forge

I want to display OpenStreetMap tiles inside forge Autodesk, but it doesn't work for me, It only gives me the color specifid for the scene

This is the code for the Forge Autodesk Extension used:

```
// Load the extension on startup, like this:
// viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv, {extensions: ['GoogleMapsExtension']});
// Result: https://youtu.be/9kVHlTV8wHw

class GoogleMapsExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
  constructor(viewer, options) {
    super(viewer, options);
  }
  quad(x, y) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xf5f5f5,
      // depthWrite: false,
    });
    
  const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 
        `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/7/${59157 + x}/${40217 - y}.png` 
    );

    material.map = texture;

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(70000, 70000),
      material
    );
    mesh.position.set(x * 256, y * 256, 1);
    return mesh;
  }

  load() {
    this.viewer.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT,
      () => {
        // console.log(this.viewer.overlays.addScene("map"));
        if (!this.viewer.overlays.hasScene("map")) {
          this.viewer.overlays.addScene("map");
        }
        const tiles = new THREE.Object3D();
        tiles.position.set(-2140, -1800, -45);
        tiles.scale.set(2, 2, 1);
        const tilex = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
        const tiley = [0, 1, 2];
        tilex.map((x) => {
          tiley.map((y) => {
            tiles.add(this.quad(x, y));
          });
        });
        window.tiles = tiles;
        console.log(tiles);
        this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(tiles, "map");
      }
    );
    return true;
  }
  unload() {
    return true;
  }
}
Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
  "GoogleMapsExtension",
  GoogleMapsExtension
);
```

This is the viewer functions file:

```
/* global Autodesk, THREE */
import { getForgeAccessToken } from "./../../services/api";

export async function init(container) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    const data = await getForgeAccessToken();
    const options = {
      env: "AutodeskProduction",
      accessToken: data.access_token,
      isAEC: true,
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      const config = {
        extensions: ["GoogleMapsExtension"],
      };

      const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(
        container,
        config
      );
      viewer.start();
      viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
      resolve(viewer);
    });
  });
}

export function loadModel(viewer, urn) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
      // console.log(doc.getRoot().search({ role: "3d", type: "geometry" })[0]);
      resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()));
    }
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(code, message, errors) {
      // console.log("onDocumentLoadFailure");
      reject({ code, message, errors });
    }
    viewer.setLightPreset(0);
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      `urn:${urn}`,
      onDocumentLoadSuccess,
      onDocumentLoadFailure
    );
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba2Bj.png)

also, I don't know where I can get the lang and lat for the cad file